# Altering menu item title results in access denied message

Tags: routes, entities

**Problem:**

When I try to overwrite the title of the edit link of a an entity built with ECK the page responds with an access denied message.

**Background:**

- I have an entity built using ECK.
- I am overwriting it's CRUD paths using hook_entity_info_alter().
- I am overwriting the add link title in hook_menu_alter() with no issue.
- I am rebuilding the menu.

**This works:**

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['myentity/add']['title'] = t('Add your Entity');
}
```

**This causes the edit link to throw an 'access denied' error:**

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$item) {
  $items['myentity/add']['title'] = t('Add your Entity'); // Still works.

  $items['myentity/%/edit']['title'] = t('Edit your Entity'); // Access Denied!
}
```

Has anyone else run into a similar issue and if so do you have a solution or work-around? Thanks.

**Update**

For fun I went into the database and manually changed the title of the menu items to see what would happen. If I just change the title directly in the database the updated title is displayed and the page works as expected.

Comment: `$items['myentity/%/edit']['title'] = t('Edit your Entity');`

Comment: Is the syntax error a copy/paste mistake or is that literally the code that's being executed?

Comment: Sorry the syntax error was just a copy/paste mistake.